# free or low cost mpeg-dash / HLS video player

Tags: video, html5-video, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

I am looking for a low cost mpeg-dash or HLS player that I can embed in my html pages? I have looked at JW player and Bitmoving but they are not completely free?

I am interested in hosting the mp4's in a cloud somewhere including .mpd or .m3u8. Encoding and how that's done is another question that I have but I would like to know what my video player options are first.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

JWPlayer is free in general, but not for MPEG-DASH, as it can be seen at there [pricing page](https://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/). Bitmovin by contrast, offers MPEG-DASH, as well as HLS playback and all there other features within the free player, as it can be seen [here](https://bitmovin.com/pricing/player-pricing/). However, these two are professional services, which have to make many somehow...

On the other hand, there are open source players, like [dash.js](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki) and [Shaka player](https://github.com/google/shaka-player) as well.

What player to choose highly depends on your use case, and how much support you will need.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will give these a try. How about segmenting video files? Is this something that people still do manually or is this no longer required? I have tried using tools to segment videos which also generate the MPD file. This works great, and I can probably automate this myself. It seems like a manual process, however. I assume many have come across this problem though. Is there a better solution out there? Thank you!

Comment: it's no longer free

Answer (score 1):

If you're considering MPEG-DASH *or* HLS... here are some HLS options.

Dailymotion released their hls.js JavaScript libary which implements a very good HLS client. But you must still build your player.
https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/

Streamroot is one of a few groups which incorporated hls.js into Brightcove's open source Video.js player and, again, shared the result with the world.
https://github.com/streamroot/videojs-hls.js

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks iangetz. Do you still need to segment your videos and create the m3u8 file manually or is there a library that makes this process easier? Thanks very much!

Comment: Yes. You should still have an encoding or packaging service that creates the .m3u8 for delivery to the player. Although it does not need to be a manual process. That depends on your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Open Source MPEG-DASH Players are a bit hard to find for the exact purpose one is looking for, but the community is constantly working to put out a valuable DASH player for not just playing DASH content but also putting up a good GUI version that lets you interact with the different parameters involved in DASH streaming.

There are a lot of open source players that I have worked with, few of them are a bit tricky to compile but I would be happy to give you the correct procedure should you run into any errors.

Client Side Player Development:
For OS: Linux 16.04, till now I have worked with, Dash.js and Shaka Player for putting on a website using HTML and an apache server. I've worked with libdash for desktop version client (qtsampleplayer). They all serve well for demo purposes but again if you want to be sure that they don't breakdown at some point, you'd require some amount of support.

Content Encoding and Segmentation: 
I simply followed this easy set of two tutorials [here](https://blog.streamroot.io/encode-multi-bitrate-videos-mpeg-dash-mse-based-media-players/) for encoding via ffmpeg and segmenting via MP4Box.

MPD File Verification: 
In case you wanted to write the mpd file yourself, you can validate it from [here](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=605)!

Cheers!